# Revoke MySQL Privileges on no longer existing Table

Tags: mysql, permissions

I created a mysql user with table level permissions.

This table is removed after a while, but the permission in mysql.table_priv are still existing.

Is there a way (maybe StoredProcedure) to remove all entries in mysql.table priv which refer to not existing tables?

Here is a way to reproduce it:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;
CREATE TABLE test (Col1 INT(10));
GRANT SELECT ON test.test TO test@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
DROP TABLE test;


SELECT * FROM mysql.tables_priv WHERE user = 'test'; # 1 row
```

Greetings
Andre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following query to find all privileges for users on tables that don't exist anymore:

```
SELECT tables_priv.* FROM mysql.tables_priv 
 LEFT JOIN information_schema.tables ON (db=table_schema AND tables_priv.table_name=tables.table_name) 
WHERE tables.table_schema IS NULL;
```

After that you can use `DELETE` to remove the privileges:

```
DELETE mysql.tables_priv FROM mysql.tables_priv 
 LEFT JOIN information_schema.tables 
  ON (db=table_schema AND tables_priv.table_name=tables.table_name) 
 WHERE tables.table_schema IS NULL;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I hope I don't have to say this, but use with extreme care.

Answer (score 1):

If the user can also be removed you can use

[DROP USER test](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-user.html)

If this is not an option I think you need to delete the corresponding entires from the `mysql.tables_priv` yourself. You need the right privileges to do this. And do not forget to flush privileges after the change.

```
DELETE FROM mysql.tables_priv 
WHERE Table_name LIKE "test" 
  AND User Like "test" 
  AND Host LIKE "%"
  AND Table_priv LIKE "Select";

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [REVOKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/revoke.html) Command:

```
REVOKE
  priv_type [(column_list)]
  [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
ON [object_type] priv_level
FROM user [, user] ...
```

Be careful in that table!

Comment: I want to keep the user so DROP USER is no option.

I have about 1000 mysql users and don´t know which tables are removed in the last month.

Comment: I see. Well then you probably need a function or procedure that cleans it out.